# how can I "alias" make to some different command

Tags: makefile

I have a source code that is written in c#, which can be either build using makefile (which requires me to generate it, and I am quite lazy for that) or execute xbuild in root of source code, which then build that very project I am in.

Or I can execute my own shell script (build.sh) which will build everything, and put it all together so that users don't need to bother with understanding how things work in my project.

However, most of linux users are familiar with `./configure && make` standard. I would like to enable this standard in my project as well, but I want make to just execute my script "build.sh" and exit (eventually with error if my script fail)

Is it possible to do that? For example some simple makefile which doesn't do anything but execute some other shell script?

My goal is that users open directory with my source code, and if they are actually lazy to read the readme :-) they can still type `./configure && make` which will actually work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example `Makefile` which should do the job:

```
all:
        $(CURDIR)/build.sh
```

When running `make` it will run the `build.sh` script in the same directory as the `Makefile`.

Comment: ./build.sh should suffice; I'd be interested in seeing a case where that does not work, and curdir is needed, as I have yet to find one.

Comment: I find it nice to see the absolute path in the output log; it's simply a matter of taste, but quite useful when you have multiple `Makefile`s in different directories.